# CSVs in Python with newline in quotes

Tags: python, csv

I get the impression that this is a common problem, I have a csv file with newlines within the fields. I am looking for a fix within Python--and within the csv module if possible.

Here is an example file that I have created

```
$ more test_csv.csv
a,"b",c,d,"e
e
e",f
a,bb,c,d,ee ,"f
f"
a,b,"c
c",d,e,f
```

Not all fields will be wrapped in quotes (although my usage is random in this example, the actual file should match quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

The output should resemble

```
[[a,b,c,d,"e\ne\ne",f],[a,bb,c,d,ee,"f\nf"][a,b,"c\nc",d,e,f]]
```

Instead I am getting

```
[[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e\n']], [['e']], [['e"', 'f']], [['a', 'bb', 'c', 'd', 'ee ', 'f\n']], [['f"']], [['a', 'b', 'c\n']], [['c"', 'd', 'e', 'f']]]
```

Please focus on the amount of rows and columns. Another concern is that in the thirds row, a quote was included when it should not have been.

Here is my code so far:

import csv

```
file = open('test_csv.csv', 'r')
rows = []
for line in file:
  fields = []  
  mycsv = csv.reader([line], dialect='excel', \
    quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
  for field in mycsv:
    fields.append(field)
  rows.append(fields)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Note in the answer there that you must open the file in binary mode.

Comment: By looping over `mycsv` you are looping over whole *rows*, not columns. Don't loop over the `file` object at all.

Comment: @Claudiu 's response clarifies that the file need not be read in as binary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of splitting the lines yourself, let `csv.reader` do it:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> file = StringIO("""a,"b",c,d,"e
e
e",f
a,bb,c,d,ee ,"f
f"
a,b,"c
c",d,e,f""")
>>> for line in csv.reader(file):
    print line

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e\ne\ne', 'f']
['a', 'bb', 'c', 'd', 'ee ', 'f\nf']
['a', 'b', 'c\nc', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Further explanation: By looping over the lines yourself, and creating a read for each line, you are logically treating the file as if each line was a separate and complete csv file. Instead, you want to treat the whole file as a csv document. You can either do this by passing the file object into `csv.reader`, since iterating over a file object iterates over the lines of the file, or reading the file yourself, splitting the lines by newlines, and then passing in the list of **all** the split lines into **one** `csv.reader`.

Comment: Summary:  `csv.reader` parses files, not lines.